# Delphi Datasnap Callback - Avisar o Client sobre alguma coisa

Tags: delphi, datasnap, delphi-xe7

Estou começando agora a implementar em Datasnap.
Procurei bastante mas não encontrei solução, talvez pela minha inexperiência, esteja deixando passar algo muito simples.

Preciso encontrar uma forma de enviar uma mensagem para os client conectados ao server. Por exemplo quero avisar tal client que ele precisa se atualizar, encerrar sua conexão ou quem sabe exibir uma mensagem na tela do usuário.

Li vários artigos e baixei diversos exemplos sobre Callback, mas pelo que pude entender, pelo menos nos exemplos, é que somente o client chama o Callback, ele requisita ao server e o server responde, preciso fazer o inverso disso, é possível?

Grato

Answer (score -1):

Isso é possível sim, através de callback mesmo. Quem dispara o callback é o server, e o client recebe a mensagem e processa.

Dê uma lida neste artigo, ele explica certinho como implementar callback tanto no client como no server: https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41374

Em resumo, no seu client você se registra num canal de callback e passa um método que será executado toda vez que receber uma mensagem, e no server você dispara um broadcast no mesmo canal, e todos os clients registrados irão receptar a mensagem, sendo possível passar parâmetros nessas mensagens.